# jQuery update not replacing js files in Drupal 6.16

Tags: jquery, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I am using jquery update in drupal 6.16 along with a lot of other modules.

I am trying to use jquery ui 1.7.2 to render tabs. But unfortunately they don't work properly since jquery update is not replacing the jquery file (jquery 1.3.2). I checked the version using `$.fn.jquery` (in firebug) and got 1.2.6 (not 1.3.2 as required) as the result - and as expected the aggregated js file was using the 1.2.6 version of jquery (see source).

earlier I had just replaced the core script files in `/misc` with the js files in `sites/default/modules/jquery_update/replace` folder (like you'd do in 5.x) and got the necessary result (i also renamed jquery.min.js to jquery.js ).

now suddenly that stopped working after i upgraded to 6.x-2.0-alpha1 and also installed the mollom module. disabling/uninstalling mollom or down-grading jQuery update does not seem to help.

the problem only occurs on the front page though. other content pages have jQuery 1.3.2

the problem can be seen [here](http://www.whackk.com/).

So, basically, for some reason, jquery update is not replacing the jquery files (as it is supposed to) on the front page. and i cannot figure out why that happens.

any ideas?

Comment: Have you made sure to clear all of your caches? It looks like you have JS aggregation enabled.

Comment: yes, JS and CSS aggregation is enabled. It seems jquery update IS replacing the file now. 

but still the jquery UI tabs i am using on that page do not seem to work. any ideas why that might be happening?

Comment: Firefox + Firebug is your friend.  When loading the page I get a syntax error due to a missing closing parenthesis.

Comment: This one, right? : uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: )

I don't know how I can resolve this one. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following issue attempts at solving the problem of an updated jquery not being used. Follow this [link](http://drupal.org/node/813918) to see the whole discussion.

There is a problem with the jquery_update.module file.

Prior to jQuery 1.3.2, all the header information was in the form:

```
/*
* jQuery 1.2.6 - New Wave Javascript
```

jQuery Update was matching on the number to see if it should override Drupal's included JS file.

Since v1.3.2, the header information is now in the form:

```
/*
* jQuery JavaScript Library v1.3.2
```

The pattern matching fails and the module reverts to Drupal's default jQuery file.
The correct replacement pattern should be:

`$pattern = '# \* jQuery JavaScript Library v([0-9\.]+)#';`

This replacement should be done in the file jquery_update.module, line 91.